# How to find the path of JDBC driver in CentOS

Tags: centos

I ma using CentOS 6.7. I want to know the path where the JDBC driver is located. The whereis jdbc command returns jdbc: so I think the JDBC driver is installed, but I need to know its exact path.

Comment: The `locate jdbc` command will display the files containing jdbc, the locate database is updated with the `updatedb` command. The `whereis` command will find for you binaries, sources or man pages in your case it did not find a binary called `jdbc`.

Comment: DESCRIPTION
       `whereis`  locates the binary, source and manual files for the specified command names.  The supplied names are first stripped of leading pathname components and any
       (single) trailing extension of the form .ext (for example: .c) Prefixes of s.  resulting from use of source  code  control  are  also  dealt  with.   whereis  then
       attempts to locate the desired program in the standard Linux places, and in the places specified by $PATH and $MANPATH.

Answer (score 2):

the locate jdbc command wasn't helpful for me. But I have found the path where JDBC driver is installed. Basically I wanted to know the JDBC driver path for installing Apache Ranger through in Apache Ambari. Apache Ambari would display the following message:

> Execute the following command on the Ambari Server host. Replace
>   database-type with mysql|oracle|postgres|mssql|sqlanywhere and
>   /jdbc/driver/path based on the location of corresponding JDBC driver:
>   ambari-server setup --jdbc-db={database-type}
>   --jdbc-driver={/jdbc/driver/path}

The JDBC driver on my centOS is /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar so I executed the following command with the correct driver path

> ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql
>   --jdbc-driver=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar